# how to populate video thumb nail from url in android

Tags: android, android-video-player

in my app i need to populate video thumb nail form of list of urls in a list view. but i do not know how to do that?. i am playing video from url by the following code. is there any way to get thumb nail video from the code.

my code:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
   myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
   myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   myVideoView.requestFocus();
   myVideoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can show Video Thumbnail if your video are in Sdcard...

follow this link...
http://sadeqbillah.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/showing-video-thumbnails-in-android-2-0/

Comment: can show Video Thumbnail from url? not from sdcard. how to get thumbnail of url. what is the steps to do it?.please help me.

Comment: how to get thumb nail from url. please help me.

Comment: can we get video thumb nail from url. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails -> getThumbnail()
@
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.html

Comment: can show Video Thumbnail from url? not from sdcard. how to get thumbnail of url. what is the steps to do it?.please help me.

Comment: thanks, how can we get it? please point out some links or examples.